# Swift 3: How to read from "Optional(Optional(stringValue))" without optional?

Tags: swift

I got the string value from server like this.

```
let filename = "\(eventList[index]["filename"])"
```

But I got the value with **Optional(Optional(stringValue))**.
So I changed that like this.

```
let filename = "\(eventList[index]["filename"]!)"
```

Then I got the value with **Optional(stringValue)**.
I can't do any more for this error.
How can I read the filename without any optional?

Comment: Use one more "**!**" after bracket close. However, it's better if you use **if let** syntax.

Comment: Unwrap – aka take control of –  the optional(s) properly.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nil-coalescing operator aka double question mark operation. It is used to provide a default value when unwrapping an optional type.

```
let filename = eventList[index]["filename"] ?? ""
```

R̶e̶f̶:̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶w̶w̶w̶.̶j̶e̶e̶n̶a̶l̶i̶n̶f̶o̶t̶e̶c̶h̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶b̶l̶o̶g̶s̶/̶i̶o̶s̶/̶h̶o̶w̶-̶t̶o̶-̶d̶o̶-̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶a̶l̶-̶v̶a̶r̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶-̶a̶s̶s̶i̶g̶n̶m̶e̶n̶t̶-̶w̶i̶t̶h̶-̶d̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶-̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶-̶d̶o̶u̶b̶l̶e̶-̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶-̶m̶a̶r̶k̶/̶

https://medium.com/@milanpanchal24/

Answer (score 0):

Use `if-let` syntax to unwrap optional:

```
if let fileName = eventList[index]["filename"] {
    // use fileName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`eventList[index]` accesses an array item at the given index. The item you are referring seems to be an optional dictionary so before accessing the dictionary item it needs to be unwrapped: `eventLists[index]!` (assuming it exists and valid of course otherwise it will crash)

then you can access the dictionary require value which is an optional as well:

```
eventLists[index]!["fileName"]!
```

assuming your list is valid you will get the desired `String` object.

I recommend using the safety checks (`if-let` or other variants) for preventing crashes